# Flutter matching pattern

Tags: flutter

I'm following

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-exception-handling-try-catch-result-type/

This part raises an exception in the compiler

The type is:

```
Future<Result<String, Exception>>
```

Sample

```
// Use like this:
final result = await getLocationFromIP('122.1.4.122');
final value = switch (result) {
  Success(value: final location) => location.toString(),
  Failure(exception: final exception) => 'Something went wrong: $exception',
};
```

AndroidStudio wants to add the following line after "ToDo":

```
final value = switch (result) {
      Success(value: final rvalue) => rvalue,
      Failure(exception: final exception) => 'Something went wrong: $exception',
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      Future<Result<String, Exception>>() => throw UnimplementedError(),
    };
```

Comment: The question is not really clear did you mean android studio is suggesting you add this line to the switch statement  Future<Result<String, Exception>>() => throw UnimplementedError() are you using copilot?

Comment: if yes you don't need it because the result type is either failure or success which both case as been handle so this line Future<Result<String, Exception>>() => throw UnimplementedError(), doesn't have anything it is doing there and is not even valid so you can remove it

Comment: Somehow, result is getting inferred as "FutureOr".  Can you hover result and see what type is inferred?